# Spring MVC PUT method I got HTTP Status 405, failed redirect to another intenal view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm using Spring MVC for add & update form.
Don't know why cannot redirect back to same form to show error message while submitted BindingResult (form validation, wrong input etc..) got any errors.
This happen when using PUT method(update things), not POST method (add things)...
Please anyone suggestion what should I do.
Thanks in advance.

Error in the browser I received:

```
HTTP Status 405 - HTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL
type Status report
messageHTTP method PUT is not supported by this URL  
descriptionThe specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource.
GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 4.1.1
```

Console nothing show up... just the log I make showing which field of input got error.

Here the methods inside controller:

```
//Add - no problem can show validation error message in the JSP form
@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String saveUserDetail(@Valid UserDetail userDetail,
        Errors errors) {
    if (errors.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        log.info("User attempt create user: " + userDetail.toString());
        for (FieldError error : errors.getFieldErrors()) {
            log.info(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        //redirect to same page to show error return infor (NotEmpty etc...)
        return "/user/inputUserDetail"; //same structure for PUT method below, but not working show me 405 error
    } else {
        try {
            userDetailService.addUserDetail(userDetail);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to add new UserDetail: " + userDetail.toString());
        }
        return "redirect:/user/userDetails";
    }
}

//Update - need UserDetail model attribute
@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public ModelAndView updateUserDetail(@Valid UserDetail userDetail,
        Errors errors, Map<String, Object> map) {
    if (errors.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        log.info("User attempt update user: " + userDetail.toString());
        for (FieldError error : errors.getFieldErrors()) {
            log.info(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        //I want to redirect to same form but show validation of previous inputted got error (NotEmpty, Email, typeMissMatch etc...)
        //Below tested all failed

        //Use this when return type is String
        //return "/user/inputUserDetail"; //405 error
        //return inputUserDetail(map); //405 error, direct call another method in same controller to show update form 
        //return "redirect:/user/userDetail/" + userDetail.getUdId(); //ok, but this one is redirect, no current errors bind to the update form

        //Use this when return type is ModelAndView
        map.put(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "userDetail", errors); 
        map.put("userDetail", userDetail);

        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView();
        mv.addObject(new RedirectView("FaddistWardrobe/user/userDetail"));
        mv.addAllObjects(map);
        return mv;
    } else {
        try {
            //update user detail
            userDetailService.updateUserDetail(userDetail);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.error("Failed to update UserDetail: " + userDetail.toString());
        }
        //This one okay can perform while form data correct
        //If return String like above method, result same, both ok
        return new ModelAndView("redirect:/user/userDetails");
    }
}
```

The mapping I follow REST url style PUT method for update user, don't know it is possible cannot call internal JSP while using PUT method? Or any configuration I miss out for PUT method setup?
This webapp already configured org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter...

Appreciate & welcome any suggestions, I just started to learn Spring MVC... 
Hope someone help... Thanks again.

Comment: Because you shouldn't redirect but just render the view instead. A redirect is client side, which results in a GET to the same url, for which you then again will loose all messages errors etc.

Comment: I still not sure how spring work.. May I know how to render the page? It is just direct call => return "/user/inputUserDetail";

Comment: This return jsp page inside WEB-INF, only work when I try add user form(POST method) , but not update user form (PUT method)

Comment: A redirect and forwarding to a page is quite different at least from the handling point of view and what happens on the browser side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is trying to perform like PUT => Redirect => PUT

(1) Above code okay when try to add correct data because it perform like PUT => Redirect => GET

(2) Fail due to trying display error in the same page using PUT method

Solution is change to PUT => Redirect => GET as below coding:

```
//Update - need UserDetail model attribute
@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail", method = RequestMethod.PUT)
public String updateUserDetail(@Valid UserDetail userDetail,
        Errors errors, Map<String, Object> map,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {
    if (errors.getErrorCount() > 0) {
        //log.info("User attempt update user: " + userDetail.toString());
        for (FieldError error : errors.getFieldErrors()) {
            log.info(error.getField() + ": " + error.getDefaultMessage());
        }
        //redirect to same page to show error return infor (NotEmpty etc...)
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("userDetail", userDetail);
        redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute(BindingResult.MODEL_KEY_PREFIX + "userDetail", errors);
        return "redirect:/user/userDetail/error";
    } else {
        try {
            //update user detail
            userDetailService.updateUserDetail(userDetail);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            String tmp = e.getLocalizedMessage();
            String tmp2 = e.toString();
            //log.error("Failed to update UserDetail: " + userDetail.toString());
        }
        return "redirect:/user/userDetails";
    }
}


//Display form with validation error after update fail (PUT -> Redirect -> GET)
@RequestMapping(value = "/userDetail/error", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String inputUserDetail_error() {
    //Here will auto retrieve previous redirectAttributes data and put into the JSP page.
    return "/user/inputUserDetail";
}
```

Just use redirectAttributes store temporary model and when the user after redirected, can retrieved back previous model and use it.
Hope able help other fresh to SpringMVC with this solution.
Thanks.